# conflict with DLLs of the same name from 3rd party components

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, dynamic-linking

My project is linked against two 3rd Party dependencies. These dependencies depend on other components. Unfortunately there is a problem here, because both dependency `a` and dependency `b` **depend on the same DLL but in different versions**. This leads to an ordinal error when starting my application.

Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: No, you have to use the same versions (not 100% true, as if the code is "managed", you can use versioned dlls IIRC).

Comment: This is the kind of situation that [Side-By-Side assemblies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/side-by-side-assemblies) and [Activation Contexts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/activation-contexts) were invented to handle.  You can create an activation context that specifies dependency `a` uses version 1 of the DLL, and another context that specifies dependecy `b` uses version 2 of the DLL, and then activate the appropriate context when loading `a` and `b` at runtime.  It is possible to have multiple versions of the same DLL loaded at the same time.